# MySQL NOW() function - whose clock is used?

Tags: mysql

For the mysql NOW() function, whose system time is used for time calculations? The host of the database or the client executing the statement?

Answer (score 2):

That should be the time of the host (DB Server).

To be sure, login to MySQL from your client and run

```
SELECT NOW();
```

and then run the `date()` command in PHP and compare.

The [**NOW()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) and [**PHP date()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) would only be the same if you are running MySQL and Apache/NGINX on the same server.

## CAPTAIN's LOG : SUPPLEMENTAL

You may also compare the difference between [**NOW()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) and [**SYSDATE()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate) if you care about the datetime being deterministic.

The example in the documentation for [**SYSDATE()**] show how

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(), SLEEP(2), NOW();
+---------------------+----------+---------------------+
| NOW()               | SLEEP(2) | NOW()               |
+---------------------+----------+---------------------+
| 2006-04-12 13:47:36 |        0 | 2006-04-12 13:47:36 |
+---------------------+----------+---------------------+

mysql> SELECT SYSDATE(), SLEEP(2), SYSDATE();
+---------------------+----------+---------------------+
| SYSDATE()           | SLEEP(2) | SYSDATE()           |
+---------------------+----------+---------------------+
| 2006-04-12 13:47:44 |        0 | 2006-04-12 13:47:46 |
+---------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

Sorry, if this is WTMI, but just know that [NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) comes from the DB Server, not the WebServer.

Back in March of 2014, I talked about monkeying around with the server time and its effect on binary logs : [Risk of changing clocktime on MySQL server host](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60196/risk-of-changing-clocktime-on-mysql-server-host/60200#60200)

Comment: See also, the startup option:  `--sysdate-is-now`